# Ubuntu freezes during bitbake build do_compile

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm new to the yocto project and am trying to build an image for my hmi panel. The entire system (ubuntu 20.04) always freezes when the build gets to `qtwebengine-5.15.4+gitAUTOINC+be49f438d6_6c7b4ffb3f-r0 do_compile`

The terminal:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-guf-linux"
MACHINE              = "imx8mguf"
DISTRO               = "guf-wayland"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "dunfell-11.0-18-gb644b1d"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa53 crc crypto"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:13f4ddf50eccaeed96a40a5f1a1d4173e677e98a"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-filesystems     = "HEAD:2915810edbb6599051e30efb3b7f805665ddcc23"
meta-python2         = "HEAD:b901080cf57d9a7f5476ab4d96e56c30db8170a8"
meta-guf-machine     = "HEAD:eea8d9ca63c767ad6168a6e34314d58b96ea6ed2"
meta-guf-distro      = "HEAD:f36401f59b27972c076f2093c98b4f6ac25a7941"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:a2882fecc96019781880c38fc6a81a9b71c944ad"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:0173d3f8d0cbf7844a4d23bc3fb30144abc914bb"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:5d882cdf079b3bde0bd9869ce3ca3db411acbf3b"

Initialising tasks: 100% |########################################################| Time: 0:00:05
Sstate summary: Wanted 2352 Found 0 Missed 2352 Current 1190 (0% match, 33% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Set DISTRO_VERSION='dunfell-11.0-18-gb644b1d' for distro guf-wayland (matches tags with dunfell[-/]*)
Currently  1 running tasks (3945 of 8508)  46% |######################                          |
0: qtwebengine-5.15.4+gitAUTOINC+be49f438d6_6c7b4ffb3f-r0 do_compile (pid 3551)   0% |          |
```

I tried disabling parallel make by setting `BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "1"` and `PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 1"` , but that didn't change anything.

Do you know what could cause this and how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 and it only got stuck like that once. If it did I just had to cleanse the recipe and restart the build

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue before, it is `RAM` related issue.

I used to work on 8Go RAM PC, I added 8Go RAM and it compiled without error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have 16 GBs of RAM already. Is that the only change you made?